# Counterexample of a field extension which is unramified for all finite places but ramified for an infinite place

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

While I was reading global class field theory I read the theorem about Hilbert class fields. After that I came to this question. Is it possible to find an extension of number fields that is unramified for all finite places but ramified for an infinite place? Maybe it is wrong and we have this: Given an extension of number fields that is unramified for all finite places, then it is unramified for all infinite places.

Comment: ${\mathbb Q}(i,\sqrt{-3})/{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is ramified only at infinity.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer This solves my question, thanks. Let $F$ be a number field and consider its maximal abelian extension $K$, which is unramified at the finite places of $\mathcal{O}_F$. Can we say something about its degree or even about its Galois group?

Comment: Look up the narrow class group or narrow class number.  The field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$ has (ordinary) class number $1$ and narrow class number $2$.

Comment: @KCd This is exactly the perfect answer I was looking for, thank you.